# If $abc$ is its own inverse...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dr. Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* presents the exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $a,b,c$ denote elements of $G$, and let $e$ be the neutral element of $G$.
>
> Prove the following:
>
> 4. If $abc$ is its own inverse, then $bca$ is its own inverse, and $cab$ is its own inverse.

Does the first sentence mean:

$$abc=(abc)^{-1}$$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what that sentence means.  Alternately, it means $abcabc=e$ where $e$ is the identity.

Comment: That's exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is also often expressed as $(abc)(abc)=e$, for the multiplicative identitiy $e$.