# a=a^{-1} iff aa=e

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dr. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents the following exercise from Chapter 4, "Elementary Properties of Groups."

> Let G be a group. Let a,b,c denote elements of G, and let e be the neutral element of G.
>
> $$a=a^{-1} \text{ iff aa=e.}$$

A previous [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282143/if-abc-is-its-own-inverse#comment2603146_1282143) had already explained that, if $$abc=(abc)^{-1}$$, then $$abcabc=e$$.

To prove the first part, then I can do:

$$a=a^{-1}$$

$$a(a)=a(a^{-1})$$

Finally, $$aa=e$$.

Does this prove the above question?

Comment: It does indeed prove the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown that $a=a^{-1}\implies aa=e$, you also need to prove $aa=e\implies a=a^{-1}$.  You could string your equations together with $\iff$.